# Net Usage (%) of a Process in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, process

I'm trying to build a script in Linux (Debian 10) that shows the net usage (%) of a process passed as an argument.
This is the code, but there isn't any output:

```sh
ProcessName=$1
(nethogs -t ens33 | awk '/$ProcessName/{print $3}') &> output.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While using tracemode `nethogs -t`, first field of output is program and it can consists of irregular number of arguments.
In case of brave:

```
/usr/lib/brave-bin/brave --type=utility --utility-sub-type=network.mojom.NetworkService --field-trial-handle=18208005703828410459,4915436466583499460,131072 --enable-features=AutoupgradeMixedContent,DnsOverHttps,LegacyTLSEnforced,PasswordImport,PrefetchPrivacyChanges,ReducedReferrerGranularity,SafetyTip,WebUIDarkMode --disable-features=AutofillEnableAccountWalletStorage,AutofillServerCommunication,DirectSockets,EnableProfilePickerOnStartup,IdleDetection,LangClientHintHeader,NetworkTimeServiceQuerying,NotificationTriggers,SafeBrowsingEnhancedProtection,SafeBrowsingEnhancedProtectionMessageInInterstitials,SharingQRCodeGenerator,SignedExchangePrefetchCacheForNavigations,SignedExchangeSubresourcePrefetch,SubresourceWebBundles,TabHoverCards,TextFragmentAnchor,WebOTP --lang=en-US --service-sandbox-type=none --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100/930/1000   0.0554687   0.0554687
```

so `$3` will no longer be as expected, you need to get last column of output using `$(NF)` as follow:

```
... | awk /$ProcessName/'{print $(NF)}'
```

for second last column:

```
... | awk /$ProcessName/'{print $(NF - 1)}'
```

Answer (score 0):

> What I'm doing wrong?

What you're doing wrong is single-quoting `$ProcessName` while wanting this to be parameter-expanded. To get the expansion, just don't quote there, e. g.:

```
… awk /$ProcessName/'{print $3}' …
```

Comment: Ops! Didn't notice! Thanks for your time, really appreciated! :)